# Multiple page objects in one test case

Tags: nightwatch.js

So far the example is only using one page object in a test case. Can we have multiple page objects in a test case?

Imagine that I have a test case which required to login, and then followed by creating an user.

So I have two page objects, one for login page and another for user page. We will use the page objects like this?

```
module.exports = {
  'login': function (browser) {
    var login = browser.page.login();
    login.navigate()
      .click('@submit');
  },
  'create user': function (browser) {
    var users = browser.page.users();
    users.navigate()
      .click('@submit')
      .end();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code would be like :

```
 module.exports = {
  'create user': function (browser) {
    const pages = browser.page,
       login = pages.login(),
       userPage = pages.users();

    login.navigate()
         .setValue('@username','myuser')
         .setValue('@pass','mypass')
         .click('@submit',function(){
               users.navigate()
                    .click('@submit')
                    .end();
               })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the example works! So we cannot do it using two test steps?