# Is it possible to use multiple page objects in a single test without chaining?

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js, pageobjects, cucumberjs

I have 3 page objects : main.js,login.js and menu.js and assuming they have functions are named the same as file name, which are series of test

- main : main()
- login : login()
- menu : menu()

For example I have the following in main.js

```
module.exports={
  commands=[{
      main:function(){
        return this.click("@login")
      }
  }],
  elements:{
     login: {
       locateStrategy:'xpath'
       selector: ('//a[@name="Log in"]')
      }
  }
}
```

One of the sequence of tests is main -> login -> menu.

I tried the following :

```
var main = client.page.main()
var login = client.page.login()
var menu=client.page.menu()
...
var ok=main.main()
if(!ok){
 return ok
}else {
 return login.login()&&menu.menu()
}
```

but keep getting error message :

```
{ status: -1,
  value:
   { error: 'invalid session id',
     message: 'No active session with ID null',
     stacktrace: '' },
  errorStatus: 6,
  error: '' }
```

How the client is changed by calling the page object?
and any suitable solution for my problem ? 
I have checked [Multiple page objects in one test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354434/multiple-page-objects-in-one-test-case), but it isn't really helpful to my case, because I have to reuse these objects multiple times.(Not just A->B->C, maybe A->C->B or A->C)

Comment: Why isn't that link helpful? What about the code there makes it to where you can't use the page objects in whatever order you want in each test?

Comment: What I want to achieve is like `main.main();login.login();menu.menu();`without levels of call backs, but on the same client(browser)

Comment: what is  `main()` in `var ok=main.main()`  ?

Comment: I just updated the question for an example of main() I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the linked question I mentioned above, I found a working solution by adding extra **callback** in each page object.

Main.js:

```
module.exports={
  commands=[{
      main:function(callback){
        return this.click("@login")
                   .perform(callback)
      }
  }],
  elements:{
     login: {
       locateStrategy:'xpath'
       selector: ('//a[@name="Log in"]')
      }
  }
}
```

Login.js

```
module.exports={
      commands=[{
          login:function(callback){
            return this.setValue("@id",'admin')
                       .setValue("@pw",'admin')
                       .perform(callback)
          }
      }],
      elements:{
         id: {
           locateStrategy:'xpath'
           selector: ('//input[@name="id"]')
          }
          pw: {
           locateStrategy:'xpath'
           selector: ('//input[@name="password"]')
          }
      }
    }
```

Menu.js:

```
module.exports={
  commands=[{
      menu:function(callback){
        return this.waitForElementVisible("@welcome")
                   .perform(callback)
      }
  }],
  elements:{
     welcome: {
       locateStrategy:'xpath'
       selector: ('//a[@name="Welcome !"]')
      }
  }
}
```

And in my test :

```
var main=client.page.main()
var login=client.page.login()
var menu=client.page.menu()
...
return main.main(function(){
          login.login(function(){
            menu.menu(function(){})
          })
       })
```

Not really the way I want to achieve(not chaining page objects), but it works this way.